# mysql retrieving data starting from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot

I have two tables in MySQL,

the first one is like this:

```
ID INFO1 INFO2 INFO3 INFO4 INFO5
1   abc   cde   fgh   ecc   ecc
2   xxx   yyy   zzz   ecc   ecc
3   abc   cde   fgh   ecc   ecc
4   abc   cde   fgh   ecc   ecc
```

the second one is like this:

```
ID1 ID2 INFO_F
 1   2   10
 2   3   23
 3   1   61
 .   .   .
```

Where ID1 and ID2 are the same IDs of the first table.

Now I need a third table like this:

```
INFO1_ID1 INFO1_ID2 INFO2_ID1 INFO2_ID2 INFO3_ID1 INFO3_ID2 INFO_F
   abc       xxx       cde      yyy       fgh       zzz       10
```

for all the records in the table2.

I hope it is clear...

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the same table twice.

```
SELECT t11.*,t12.*,t2.* FROM t2 
LEFT JOIN t1 as t11 ON t1.ID = t2.ID1
LEFT JOIN t1 as t12 ON t12.ID = t2.ID2
```

Comment: Thanks it is what I was searching for!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the join as long as you specifically name the results and tables. This may help you (you need :

```
SELECT 
    id1, id2, info_f,
    tb1a.id AS id1fromtb1, tb1a.INFO1 as info1fromtb1,
    tb1b.id, tb1b.INFO1
FROM table2
JOIN table1 as tb1a on table2.id1=tb1a.id
JOIN table1 as tb1b on table2.id2=tb1b.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0744/4